# Local repository for Oracle Solaris 11.3

Tags: solaris, solaris-studio

https://www.oracle.com/solaris/solaris11/downloads/local-repository-downloads.html

In the above link, i can see only local repository files for 11.4. Where can i download it for Solaris 11.3? Or 11.4 itself will support for 11.3 also?

I need to install Solaris studio 12.4 using IPS. In order to do that i need to create a local repository. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Solaris 11.3 downloads are only available from the [My Oracle Support portal](https://support.oracle.com/portal/) now that 11.4 has been out for over two years and 11.3 has fallen to Limited Support status.